# no output in part-00000 when running WordCount v1.0 Example

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I'm new to both Cloudera and Hadoop, and the output the Cloudera WordCount 1.0 example (part-00000) is empty. The steps and files I'm using are [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount1.html). I'm want to provide whatever job log information would help, ditto for versions - I just need some guidance on where to find them. Below is the job output and the source. Of the other parts written (part-00001 through part-00011), the non-empty ones are part-00001 (Bye 1), part-00002 (Hadoop 2), part-00004 (Goodbye 1), part-00005 (World 2), and part-00009 (Hello 2). Any help would be awesome.

Here are the  commands and output:

```
[me@server ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/me/wordcount/input/file0
Hello World Bye World

[me@server ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/me/wordcount/input/file1
Hello Hadoop Goodbye Hadoop

[me@server ~]$ hadoop jar wordcount.jar org.myorg.WordCount /user/me/wordcount/input /user/me/wordcount/output
13/11/12 10:39:41 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/11/12 10:39:41 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
13/11/12 10:39:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201311051201_0014
13/11/12 10:39:43 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/11/12 10:39:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 33% reduce 0%
13/11/12 10:39:52 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 67% reduce 0%
13/11/12 10:39:53 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
13/11/12 10:39:58 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 25%
13/11/12 10:40:01 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201311051201_0014
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 33
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:   File System Counters
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes read=313
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of bytes written=2695420
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of read operations=0
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of large read operations=0
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE: Number of write operations=0
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes read=410
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of bytes written=41
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of read operations=18
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     HDFS: Number of write operations=24
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=3
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=12
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=3
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=16392
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=61486
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=2
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=8
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=82
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Input split bytes=357
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=8
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=6
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=5
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=649
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=6
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=5
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=12
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=15650
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=3594293248
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=18375352320
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=6497697792
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormatCounter
13/11/12 10:40:04 INFO mapred.JobClient:     BYTES_READ=50

[me@server ~]$ hadoop fs -cat /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00000

[me@server ~]$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/me/wordcount/output
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:40 /user/me/wordcount/output/_SUCCESS
drwxr-xr-x   - me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/_logs
drwxr-xr-x   - me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/_logs/history
-rw-r--r--   3 me me      67134 2013-11-12 10:40 /user/me/wordcount/output/_logs/history/job_201311051201_0014_1384270782432_me_wordcount
-rw-r--r--   3 me me      81866 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/_logs/history/job_201311051201_0014_conf.xml
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          6 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00001
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          9 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00002
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00003
-rw-r--r--   3 me me         10 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00004
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          8 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00005
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00006
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00007
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00008
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          8 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00009
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00010
-rw-r--r--   3 me me          0 2013-11-12 10:39 /user/me/wordcount/output/part-00011
[me@server ~]$
```

Here's the [source](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount1_source.html?scroll=topic_5_1):

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

public class WordCount {

  public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
      while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
        output.collect(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      int sum = 0;
      while (values.hasNext()) {
        sum += values.next().get();
      }
      output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordcount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

    JobClient.runJob(conf);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are launching 12 reduce tasks (`Launched reduce tasks=12`), although there are only five outputs from the mappers: according to the tutorial you have the five outputs that are expected. In CDH3 the number of reducers was set to the number of mapper outputs: it may well be that this behaviour has changed in CDH4 - have a look in your config files to see if you have anything like `mapred.reduce.tasks` or similar.

Comment: Thanks, davek. I found this in Cloudera Manager's mapreduce1 service info: mapred.reduce.tasks: 12. "Default Number of Reduce Tasks per Job is at least 50% of the number of reduce slots across all TaskTrackers. Suggested minimum value: 12". I would think their default is reasonable...

Comment: Ah, interesting - that would be the explanation then: 7 (of the 12) Reducers are started but receive no data, thus giving rise to 7 empty files.

Comment: integrating your answer with @Binary01's, does having zero or more empty files cause empty output?

Comment: Empty *input* files won't necessarily cause empty output: the mapper that processes an empty file will just emit nothing to the reducer - it is the reducer output that determines the output files.

Answer (score 1):

This is because  the number of reducers you are using in the job is more than the number of key you actually have i.e the words. So some of the output files from the reducers are having empty.Check the default partitioner how it paritions based on the number of reducers and the key based on which it sends data to reducers i.e HashPartitioner [Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.cloudera.com/content/repositories/releases/com.cloudera.hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-320/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/partition/HashPartitioner.java)

Answer (score 0):

OK, big thanks to Binary01 and davek3 for the direction. I'll have to do some reading to understand what's going on, but for posterity's sake I'll share details here in an answer: I got it to work by compiling the [v2.0 code](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/HadoopTutorial/CDH4/Hadoop-Tutorial/ht_wordcount2.html) so it would take "-D mapred.reduce.tasks=1", which resulted in the correct output. Just for kicks I ran it on [Hamlet](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/1524/pg1524.txt) without the -D and it also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can run the simple command to combine the outputs of all the part files:

```
cat part-* > output.txt
```